# Update button and delete not working on KendoUI Grid with Javascript

Tags: asp.net, nopcommerce, kendo-ui-grid

i'm currently working on a slider which has the slider table itself different from the slider images table where the primary key of the slider table is a foreign key on the slider images table. the idea is you create a slider, save  and upload the slider images(1 or more) so when you upload the images and save its refreshes a kendoui grid with the image.The issue now is with deleting and updating some columns like (caption , Url) images from this kendoui grid. This is my view code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#productpictures-grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            type: "json",
                            transport: {
                                read: {
                                    url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("GetPromoImagesList", "PromoSlider", new {PromoSliderId = Model.PromoSliderId }))",
                                    type: "POST",
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    data: addAntiForgeryToken
                                },
                                update: {
                                    url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("UpdatePromoImage", "PromoSlider"))",
                                    type: "POST",
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                    data: addAntiForgeryToken
                                },
                                destroy: {
                                    url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("DeletePromoImage", "PromoSlider"))",
                                    type: "POST",
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                    data: addAntiForgeryToken
                                },

                              parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                                  if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                                      return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                                  }
                                  else if (operation !== "update" && options.models) {
                                      return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                                  }
                                  else if (operation !== "destroy" && options.models) {
                                      return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                                  }
                            },
                            schema: {
                                data: "Data",
                                total: "Total",
                                errors: "Errors",
                                model: {
                                    id: "PromoImageId",
```

This is my controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdatePromoImage(PromoImageRecord imageUpdate)
    {
       PromoImageRecord  image = _imageRepo.GetById(imageUpdate.PromoImageId);

        image.DisplayOrder = imageUpdate.DisplayOrder;
        image.Url = imageUpdate.Url;
        image.Caption = imageUpdate.Caption;

        _imageRepo.Update(image);

        return new NullJsonResult();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DeletePromoImage(int PromoImageId)
    {
        PromoImageRecord image = _imageRepo.GetById(PromoImageId);
        _imageRepo.Delete(image);

        return new NullJsonResult();
    }
```

When i debug i can see that the Primary key of the sliders images table is 0 and the primary key of the sliders table which is a foreign key on the sliders images table is null. so essentially it cannot identify the particular row on the grid on which the button is clicked.
please help!

Comment: As you mentioned, the problem is about the Primary key of slider images. So, take a look at the code of `GetPromoImagesList` and check if the `Id` is set properly or not.

Comment: gee, thanks i,m just seeing this...i have checked the GetPromoImagesList..the Id is set properly ...i have tried various approaches but the "promoimagerecord imageupdate" is still null...it is meant to contain the new values inputted in the in the input text feed when editing...so when i click update it has no way of updating the row with the new values inputted because it has not been stored in "promoimagerecord imageupdate".